# Is space reclaimed when I delete an index at MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have looked around the whole documentation but can't figure out if this actually happens or not. If I remove an index from a collection in MongoDB, does it delete the index files right away? Is space reclaimed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MongoDB won't automatically release diskspace after collection data or indexes are deleted. Allocating new files is a relatively slow thing compared to other functions in a high-performance databases so MongoDB keeps all previously allocated files open and available by design.

If you need to reclaim diskspace use the [repairDatabase command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/%20repairDatabase%20command) which achieves compaction as a side-effect of it's checking/fixing functionality.

An alternative that is available when using replica sets is to add a new member and let it sync- the data will be inserted fairly compactly in the replica set member's new database extent files. To compact all members you would do it in a rolling fashion, and probably force the primary to step down at the end so it can be re-synced too.